# Spring Security with OAuth2 and JWT: Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement a spring AuthorizationServer with JWT. I was able to produce JWT tokens and login until I added BCrypt to the mix. Now, when I am trying to login, I get "Bad credentials" from the API.

OAuth2Configuration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public OAuth2Configuration(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.dataSource = new Jdbc3PoolingDataSource();
        this.passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("api-client")
                .secret("verysecretivesecret")
                .scopes("READ", "WRITE", "DELETE")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit", "refresh_tokens", "password", "authorization_code");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(jwtTokenEnhancer())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtTokenEnhancer());
    }

    @Bean
    protected JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer() {
        return new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private AccountDetailsService accountDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    WebSecurityConfig(AccountDetailsService accountDetailsService) {
        this.accountDetailsService = accountDetailsService;
        this.dataSource = new Jdbc3PoolingDataSource();
        this.passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(accountDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder).and().jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

SeedData.java

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {      

    Stream.of("alan,test").map(x -> x.split(","))
            .forEach(tuple -> {
                Account user = new Account();
                user.setUsername(tuple[0]);
                user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(tuple[1]));
                user.setEmail(tuple[0]);
                user.setRoles(Collections.singletonList(role));
                user.setActive(true);
                this.accountRepository.save(user);
            });
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are the passwords in the database BCrypt encoded?

Comment: @Jeff yes they are.              user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(tuple[1]));

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I needed to make the following change to get it to work. If anyone else needs it.

```
@Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(accountDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                    .and()
                    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                    .jdbcAuthentication()
                    .dataSource(dataSource);
        }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(accountDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Really helped me

Comment: Is there a chance you can tell me what I'm doing wrong [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138227/oauth-token-full-authentication-is-required-to-access-this-resource) - It looks like I am having the same issue but it seems to have another cause behind it.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you applied a BCrypt both to WebSecurity and AuthorizationServer. So you need to keep not only BCrypt encrypted user passwords in your store, but also BCrypt encrypted client secrets for OAuth2. I guess this was not what you tried to approach.

In order to make your code working, either remove

```
   @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
```

or manually encrypt your "verysecretivesecret"

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same so I had it removed but that didn't work either.