# oauth/token Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: spring

I want to login as a user but for some reason it seems that the endpoint `oauth/token` is protected:

```
Request URL:http://192.168.0.14:8080/oauth/token
Request Method:POST
Status Code:401 
Remote Address:192.168.0.14:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PATCH,POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-store
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 06 Mar 2018 18:59:25 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
WWW-Authenticate:Bearer realm="testjwtresourceid", error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="oauth2/client"
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Interestingly enough... I get this message:

```
2018-03-06 19:59:25.766  WARN 31030 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

It seems that for some reason the whole thing runs through the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. It's clear that this does not look like BCrypt .. though I am setting BCrypt a s my password encoder:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
}

/**
 * Using {@link BCryptPasswordEncoder} for user-password encryption.
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

---

It looks like `WebSecurity` tries to encode the client secret with BCrypt O_o

```
security.jwt.client-id=CLIENT_ID
security.jwt.client-secret=CLIENT_SECRET
```

---

The entire web config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.signing-key}")
    private String signingKey;

    @Value("${security.encoding-strength}")
    private Integer encodingStrength;

    @Value("${security.security-realm}")
    private String securityRealm;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    /**
     * Nothing to configure yet.
     * @param http
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { }

    /**
     * Define routes for {@link WebSecurity}.
     *
     * @param web
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        final String[] SWAGGER_UI = {
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/webjars/**"
        };

        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/pub/**", "/users")
                .antMatchers(SWAGGER_UI);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
        return converter;
    }

    /**
     * Using {@link JwtTokenStore} for JWT access tokens.
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    /**
     * Provide {@link DefaultTokenServices} using the {@link JwtTokenStore}.
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    /**
     * We provide the AuthenticationManagerBuilder using our {@link UserDetailsService} and the {@link BCryptPasswordEncoder}.
     * @param auth
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).and()
            .authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    /**
     * Using {@link BCryptPasswordEncoder} for user-password encryption.
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * Provide {@link DaoAuthenticationProvider} for password encoding and set the {@link UserDetailsService}.
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

}
```

The OAuth config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/**")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId(resourceIds);
        }

    }

    @Value("${security.jwt.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.jwt.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${security.jwt.grant-type}")
    private String grantType;

    @Value("${security.jwt.scope-read}")
    private String scopeRead;

    @Value("${security.jwt.scope-write}")
    private String scopeWrite;

    @Value("${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
    private String resourceIds;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(clientId)
                .secret(clientSecret)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(grantType)
                .scopes(scopeRead, scopeWrite)
                .resourceIds(resourceIds);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
                .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have the following Bean created, all security configurations will use this `PasswordEncoder`. In your case, WebSecurity and AuthorizationServerSecurity.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

I am pretty sure your `security.jwt.client-secret` is a plain text.

So, what is happening is that when you make the request, your AuthorizationSecurityConfig tried to read `security.jwt.client-secret` as a BCrypt encoded string, which eventually it is not.

Hence, the whole Authentication process fails and the warning message is logged.

To resolve this, you have two options:

**First**:

Configure the AuthorizationSecurity to use `NoOpPasswordEncoder`. Here is how you can override this. Mind you `NoOpPasswordEncoder` is already deprecated.

```
@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
}
```

**Second** (Preferred):

Generate the BCrypt value of your `security.jwt.client-secret` and set it in your `application.properties/yaml`.

Thanks to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5613927/david-steiman) who cleared the doubt on a [similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40761409/979772).

Guess what, I was facing the same issue when I was looking at this question for solution. :-)

Comment: That works. As you recommended, I chose the second option! Thank you very much!