# Spring Boot Security: Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-security, authentication, bcrypt

I recently followed an authentication and authorization tutorial in spring boot security and I think I got lost when it comes to the sql. Though it is not showing any errors, even when I put the correct username and password, it still shows bad credentials. Here is my code:

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        WebUser appUser = this.appUserDAO.findUserAccount(userName);

        if (appUser == null) {
            System.out.println("User not found! " + userName);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + userName + " was not found in the database");
        }

        System.out.println("Found User: " + appUser);

        // [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN,..]
        List<String> roleNames = this.appRoleDAO.getRoleNames(appUser.getId());

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        if (roleNames != null) {
            for (String role : roleNames) {
                // ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN,..
                GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);
                grantList.add(authority);
            }
        }

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(appUser.getUsername(), //
                appUser.getPass(), grantList);

        return userDetails;
    }
```

WebUserMapper.java

```
public static final String BASE_SQL //
= "Select u.Id, u.Username, u.Pass From User u ";

@Override
public WebUser mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

    Long userId = rs.getLong("Id");
    String userName = rs.getString("Username");
    String encrytedPassword = rs.getString("Pass");

    return new WebUser(userId, userName, encrytedPassword);
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 

        // Setting Service to find User in the database.
        // And Setting PassswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());     

    }
```

This is my database:

[image]

It returns this error:

```
Found User: test/$2y$12$MemyV61IuKV7SAntLOEVqeLPPvl2snXjQwlk3RSFDmn5eWrRcHwxm
2018-10-21 20:32:57.110  WARN 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

The password is 123. I don't know why it's not working even though I typed "123" in the password.I hope you could help me. Thank you so much

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699532/spring-security-with-oauth2-and-jwt-encoded-password-does-not-look-like-bcrypt/

Comment: are you using autowired BCryptPasswordEncoder when you are saving password to database?

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode your client_secret in server side by using bcrypt encoder.

Comment: I was getting this `Encoded password does not look like BCrypt` error message when requesting an Oauth token after migrating from Spring Boot 1.5.7 to 2.0.4. Encoding the client_secret solved it. Will have to look into it to find out why though.